# How to achieve Glyphicons with "numeric subscripts" inside Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Typically, to insert a Glyphicon inside a Bootstrap 3 app, it's as simple as:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
```

etc. In many apps, however, it is typical for Glyphicons to be "customized" so that they appear with numeric superscripts like so:

[image]

Above, this red/white "*5*" bubble might indicate that the user has 5 notifications. **I'm wondering how this "*numeric superscript*" effect can be achieved in Bootstrap 3.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like this? [image]

This is just some CSS basic styling, there is afaik no "standard" and certainly no special HTML tags nor "secret" bootstrap features that supports it. Below my suggestion - modify so it fit your expectations :

```css
.rw-number-notification {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    right: -6px;
    padding: 3px 3px 2px 3px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px silver;
}
```

markup :

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">
  <span class="rw-number-notification">7</span>
</span>
```

demo with some examples -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rqfthhkx/**

[image]

NB: Not completely related, but I *do* believe, though, that it is common practice to use the `<i>` tag when you are using glyphicons, fontawesome etc

```html
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
```

at least it renders as exactly the same -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rqfthhkx/1/**

---

**Font Awesome**

Example:

```html
<i class="fa fa-envelope text-primary">
  <span class="number-notification">7</span>
</i>
```

The `.number-notification` CSS is the same, except it seems impossible to adjust the position of the number container to `fa-xx` sizes and different font-sizes. The solution is to wrap the `<i>` element into `<h>` elements and specify the `relative` position in `rem` units :

```css
.number-notification {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 3px 2px 3px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px silver;
}
.fa .number-notification {
  top: -1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}
h3 .fa .number-notification {
  top: -1.2rem;
  right: 1.2rem;
}
h2 .fa .number-notification {
  top: -1.5rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
}
h1 .fa .number-notification {
  top: -2.2rem;
  right: 1.8rem;
}
```

This should look more or less the same with different font sizes.

[image]

New fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/b86oj9gd/**

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Font Awesome icons. Got anything for those?

Comment: Hey @cst1992, have updated the answer. Hope it works.  Seems impossible to have a generic solution that works with `.fa-xx` dimension classes such as `.fa-lg`,  `.fa-7x` etc and wildly different font-sizes. But if you wrap the `.fa` elements into header classes it seems to work.

Comment: This is nice. Did the original solution(without the heading elements) have the number scaling with the icon? This kinda feels a bit disproportionate - the number looks large or the `fa` and `h5` examples and small for `h3` and bigger. But overall, nice job.